Specific indirect effects of a non-recursive SEM in lavaan
The structural equation model I am currently analyzing includes an indirect loop and I was unable to find a straightforward way to calculate specific indirect effects for it. A minimal example of a model with this problem is:
Y ~ yb*B
A ~ ax*X + ac*C
B ~ ba*A + bc*C
C ~ cb*B

Now I'd like to know, e.g., the specific incremental indirect effect of A on Y. I am aware that usually, the solution in lavaan is to use the := operator to define the paths of the indirect effect. In this case however, I would have to calculate an infinite sum:
IE_A := ba*yb + ba*cb*ac*ba*yb + ba*cb*ac*ba*cb*ac*ba*yb + ...

I found some papers on how to calculate that effect manually based on the coefficient matrix, but calculating standard errors for these would be extremely tedious and I wonder whether there is another way to do that, for example a functionality in lavaan which I have missed or another package to use for these calculations.
